# Do we feel 0.4% less body weight on mount everest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, mass, weight

Weight of the object at surface of earth(where $g=9.8066$).

considering Weight=$100~\rm kg$ ,Weight ($W_1$)=$mg$ , **mass**=$10.1972~\rm kg$

## At mount Everest top:

Height of Mount Everest = $8.848\rm km$

$$r = 6380000k + 8.848 = 6388840~\rm km$$

Considering $F=m_1g$ and r will be $6388840~\rm km$ at Mount Everest.

$$m_1g = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r_e^2}\\ \implies g= \frac{\left(6,67\times 10^{-11}~\mathrm{N\cdot m^2/kg^2}\right)\left(5.98\times 10^{24}~\rm kg\right)}{\left(6.388840\times 10^6~\rm m\right)^2}$$

## Weight of object at Mount Everest:

Weight ($W_2$)= $\text{mass}\cdot g = 10.1972 \cdot  9.7719 = 99.646~\rm kg$

Change in Weight: $$W_1-W_2 = 100 - 99.646 = 0.3538~\rm kg$$

Seems to be around $0.4\%$  less weight than surface of earth.

## My question:

Do we feel less weight on surface of Mount Everest (or have I mixed some wrong values) ?

Comment: I didn't check your math but assuming it is correct you would weigh about a lb less if your sea level weight is about 210 lbs.  I doubt you would notice, especially considering the other factors you would be facing.

Comment: Radius of Earth is not same at all places otherwise your assumption is correct.

Comment: There is also an effect due to the fact that the Earth is rotating and you have moved further from the axis of rotation.

Comment: `(1+8.8/(6371/2))^2` is `1.00553` (about 0.6%), so your calculations seem reasonable in terms of magnitude.

Comment: 0.4% is pretty small, I kinda doubt anyone would notice that.

Answer (score 4):

> Do we feel less weight on surface of Mount Everest? (Or have I mixed some wrong values?)

The answer to both of these questions is "yes". One would weight a tiny bit less on Mount Everest, but not as much less as the question poses. You have used some incorrect values and assumptions.

If you use the numbers you yourself used to compute the gravitational acceleration at sea level, you would get 9.799 m/s<sup>2</sup> rather than 9.80665 m/s<sup>2</sup>. That's a reduction of 0.28% rather than 0.4%. Another problem: using Newton's law of gravitation to calculate the gravitational acceleration at the top of Mt. Everest assumes a non-rotating, spherical Earth and also implicitly assumes there's nothing between sea level and the top of Mt. Everest.

The Earth is rotating, and that standard value of 9.80665 m/s<sup>2</sup> includes the effects of that rotation. The rotation also causes the Earth to have an equatorial bulge. A fairly accurate approximation of the Earth's gravitational at sea level in m/s<sup>2</sup> is $$g_S(\phi) = 9.780327 (1+0.0053024 \sin^2\phi-0.0000058 \sin^22\phi)\tag1$$ This is the 1967 Geodetic Reference System Formula. (There are others.)  At 27.9881 degrees (the latitude of Mt. Everest), this yields a value of 9.7917 m/s<sup>2</sup>.

Next we need to account for altitude. Linearizing Newton's law of gravity suggests that gravitational acceleration decreases by 3×10<sup>-6</sup> m/s<sup>2</sup> per meter of increased altitude:
$$\delta g_A = \frac{GM}{R^2} - \frac{GM}{(R+h)^2} \approx 2\frac{GM}{R^3}h = 2\frac{g_0}{R}h \approx 3\times10^{-6}\,\mathrm s^{-2}\, h$$ The standard value used in geodesy is 0.3086 mgals (milligals, a gal or galileo being one cm per second squared) per meter of increased altitude. In SI units, this is 3.086×10<sup>-6</sup> m/s<sup>2</sup> per meter of increased altitude. This is the free air correction.

Next we need to account for terrain. The free air correction overstates the amount by which gravitational acceleration at the surface decreases with increased altitude. This correction, as the name suggests, assumes there's nothing but air between sea level and the altitude in question. Instead, there's 8+ kilometers of rock between sea level and the top of Mt. Everest. There are a number of techniques, some very sophisticated, for accounting how terrain affects gravitational acceleration at some locale. The various gravity anomalies that result can be very useful in suggesting where to drill or mine for minerals.

I'm going to use a simple gravity anomaly, the free air anomaly: $$\begin{align}\delta g_A &= 0.3086\,\frac{\mathrm{mgal}}{\mathrm m} \,h \tag2\\ \mathit{FA} &= g_\text{obs} - g_S(\phi) + \delta g_A \tag3\end{align}$$
In the 1970s, scientists took a gravimeter to measure $g_obs$, the observed value of gravitational acceleration, throughout Nepal ([Kono](http://ddfe.curtin.edu.au/gravitymodels/GGMplus/hirt2013_ultrahighres_gravity.pdf)). They found a fairly accurate expression for the free air anomaly in the high Himalayas:$$\mathit{FA} = -265.07 \mathrm{mgal} + 0.1014\frac{\mathrm{mgal}}{\mathrm m}\, h \tag4$$
Using equation (1), the nominal gravitational acceleration at sea level at the altitude of Mt. Everest is 9.79174 m/s<sup>2</sup>. Using equations (2) and (3), the free air correction and free air anomaly for an altitude of 8848 meters are 0.027305 and 0.006321 m/s<sup>2</sup>, leading to a reduction from sea level of 0.020984 m/s<sup>2</sup>. The gravity at the top of Mt. Everest should be about 9.77072 m/s<sup>2</sup>.

There are more sophisticated techniques than the above. Recently, work has been done combining multiple gravity models with terrain data to yield high resolution gravity field maps ([Hirt](http://gji.oxfordjournals.org/content/39/2/283.full.pdf+html.)). A downsampled version of the GGMplus map for the area around Mt. Everest is portrayed below; click on the image to see the high resolution version. Mt. Everest is the tiny patch of dark blue near 28 N latitude 87 E longitude. The value of gravitational acceleration at the peak of Mt. Everest based on this map is 9.76924 m/s<sup>2</sup>, which is close to the value obtained using a fitted free air anomaly.

[image: High Himalaya gravity acceleration]

---

[Hirt, Christian, et al. "New ultrahigh‐resolution picture of Earth's gravity field." Geophysical Research Letters 40.16 (2013): 4279-4283.](http://ddfe.curtin.edu.au/gravitymodels/GGMplus/hirt2013_ultrahighres_gravity.pdf)

[Kono, Masaru. "Gravity anomalies in east Nepal and their implications to the crustal structure of the Himalayas." Geophysical Journal International 39.2 (1974): 283-299.](http://gji.oxfordjournals.org/content/39/2/283.full.pdf+html.)